# Changing text to an input with all text selected

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which changes the linked text of a DIV into an input.

```
var input = "<input type='text' class='class_type' value='" + value + "'/>";
$(this).parent.find(".name").html(input);
```

I am aware you can use .select(), but adding this to to the end of the second line does not work.

I tried using $('.class_type').select() which worked. However, if the page has multiple input fields of the same class, the last input field on the page is selected instead of the one which was just changed into an input field.

An alternative solution would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us more information on how this being applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var input = "<input type='text' class='class_type' value='" + value + "'/>";
$(input).appendTo($(this).parent().find(".name").empty()).select();
```

or

```
var input = "<input type='text' class='class_type' value='" + value + "'/>";
var $parent = $(this).parent();
$parent.find(".name").html(input);
$parent.find(".class_type").select()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're still dealing with the parent `.name` element. You're adding an `<input>` element inside that parent element, but then calling `.select()` on the `.name` element instead of the input field inside it.

You need to navigate down to the new `<input>` element and call `select()` on that instead.
Like this:

```
$(this).parent.find(".name").html(input)
    .find('input')  // find the input field we just added
    .select();      // ...and call select on it
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.